# how to parse a string containing integers and numbers

Tags: java, string, parsing

Lets say the input is C3F5G10

i know for a fact that every other even number is a character, and every odd number is a integer. However, this only works IF the integer is a single digit. In this case its not, as 10 is read as a 2 separate elements.

How do I get around this situation? basically the output will just print the number of characters that is beside the integer

CCCFFFFFGGGGGGGGGG

```
 public static String translate(String formatStr) {
        char [] array = formatStr.toCharArray();
    char [] carray = new char[array.length/2];
    char [] narray = new char[array.length/2];
    StringBuilder build1 = new StringBuilder();



    int m = 0;
    for(int i  = 0; i<carray.length; i++){
        carray[i] = array[m];
        m+=2;
    }
    int l =1;
    for(int i = 0; i<narray.length; i++){
        narray[i] = array[l];
        l+=2;
    }



    for(int i = 0; i < carray.length; i++){
        String number = Character.toString(narray[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<Integer.parseInt(number);j++){
            build1.append(carray[i]);   
        }

        }

    return build1.toString();
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I just saw a question JUST like this. It's like you're all coming here for programming help.

Comment: I guess a relevant question to ask would be "What have you tried?"

Comment: I think you people have got a same homework 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171289/why-my-java-code-doesnt-work/20171350?noredirect=1#comment30070562_20171350

Comment: @SimplyPanda: It's the end of term. They all need help with their programming homework.

Comment: interesting, this was actually a coding competition we had at our school today. its over now and i was doing some of the problems on my own

Comment: And besides... this could be done in just one line with regex and StringUtils.repeat command :P

Comment: Well his question said "letter,digit" so I answered acoordingly. Just keep reading while `Integer.parseInt` doesnt throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

As I strongly believe that the only way person can learn something is by doing it by himself, I'll provide you some insights, and you'll code it yourself.
Keep a variable which holds the temporary number, say `num`. Read your string from left to right into the variable named `currentChar`, char by char. If current letter is character, then you know **what** you need to print; save it in a variable `charToPrint`. If it's digit, then make the following change: `num = num * 10 + <convert-your-character-to-integer> currentChar`. The next time you meet the character, you can print the previous found character, `charToPrint`, `num` times. After that assign 0 to num.
Hope that'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
  public static String translate(String word) {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    char let = ' ';
    String num = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            num += ch;
        } else if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            if (num.length() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Integer.parseInt(num); j++) {
                    res.append(let);
                }
            }
            let = ch;
            num = "";
        }
    }
    if (num.length() > 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Integer.parseInt(num); j++) {
            res.append(let);
        }
    }
    return res.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this implementation. I hope it helps.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "C3F5G10";
    StringBuilder sBuilderChar = new StringBuilder();
    String digit = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (isCharacter(input.charAt(i))) {
            int k = i;// store index of character.
            // loop until the next character is not encountered
            // form a string of all the digits sandwiched between two
            // characters
            while (k < input.length() - 1 && isDigit(input.charAt(k + 1))) {
                digit = digit + input.charAt(k + 1);
                k++;
            }
            // convert the digit string to number
            int n = Integer.parseInt(digit);
            // append the character the number of times calculated
            // previously
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                sBuilderChar.append(input.charAt(i));
            }
            // skip all the digits and move to next character
            // i.e. current index + the length of digit obtained
            i = i + digit.length();
            // empty the digit string
            digit = "";
        }

    }
    // print the string formed to console
    System.out.println(sBuilderChar);

}

public static boolean isDigit(char c) {
    // digits are in the range [48,57] in ASCII code
    return c >= 48 && c <= 57;
}

public static boolean isCharacter(char c) {
    // if not digit then 'c' is a character
    return !isDigit(c);
}

}
```

Comment: It should print `CCCFFFFFGGGGGGGGGG` not `CFG`.

Comment: @Masud yes, I have rectified it and posted the correct answer.Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Seems to work. The lines from `int tmp=0` are of interest to you. This is how I would deal with multiple digits after a character.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionTwo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    char[] input = sc.nextLine().trim().toCharArray();

    StringBuilder ans = new StringBuilder("");
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
      if (i > input.length - 1)
        break;
      // Has to be a character.
      char c = input[i];
      i++;
      int tmp = 0;
      while (i < input.length && Character.isDigit(input[i])) {
        tmp *= 10;
        tmp += input[i] - '0';
        i++;
      }
      while (tmp-- > 0)
        ans.append(c);
    }
    out.println(ans.toString());
    out.close();
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use regex, then here is a way...

```
 public static String translate(String formatStr) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    //make sure it really contains just alphanumeric
    if(formatStr.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")) {
        String alphas[] = removeInvalid(formatStr.split("[0-9]"));
        String numerics[] = removeInvalid(formatStr.split("[a-zA-Z]"));
        int alphaPointer = 0;
        for(String num: numerics) {
            int iterator = Integer.valueOf(num);
            for(int i=0; i< iterator; i++) {
                result.append(alphas[alphaPointer]);
            }
            alphaPointer++;
        }
    }
    return result.toString();

}

/*
 * Remove empty results from the regex split 
 */
private static String[] removeInvalid(String[] values) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String value: values) {
        if(value.matches("\\d+") || value.matches("\\w+"))
            list.add(value);
    }
    String[] valids = new String[list.size()];
    return list.toArray(valids);
}
```